# Grouping items in the listview with image

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-7, grouping

I am using [this code](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/delphi-list-view-groups-expand-collapse-items.htm) to group the items in my listview. But what I want is the Image size of the Group title will stay "16x16", while the image of the items within the group will have a different size e.g. 50x50.

How do I do that for Delphi 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article code is only **simulating** groups by manipulating normal list items, so group title images and item images utilize the same `TListItem.ImageIndex` property and thus will be accessing the same image list, so they must use same sized images.

The standard Win32 ListView control supports using different image lists for group titles and list items (Vista+ only, though).

I would suggest abandoning the article code and either:

1. use the Win32 API directly to enable the ListView's [native grouping features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Group_View).  Just because Delphi 7's `TListView` component does not natively support the grouping API does not prevent you from using it manually.  You might have to define the relevant record types and message IDs manually in your code, that's all.
2. switch to [SoftGem's Virtual TreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) (which does support Delphi 7) to create a columned list view with expandable/collapsible items. Individual tree nodes can have different heights, and they can be owner-drawn, so I imagine it would not be difficult to display different sized images for groups and items.